# Pathfinding with conditions / dynamic obstacles

Tags: dynamic, path-finding

I am trying to solve a complex path-finding problem and I am struggling at finding a solution.

Let's explain briefly. A player is in a grid made of mountains (always an obstacle), oceans (initially obstacle but can become navigable when a boat is available) and plains/hills/forests/rivers (not obstacles but with different "walking costs" i.e life reduction).

We start with a given life level (250) and each action costs life (and bring score points).

The map also contains 10 dungeons (9 conventional, fully accessible by walking) and the last one on an island only accessible with the boat (so we must have one). You need to have a minimum level of life (100 min) to enter a dungeon and each dungeon reduce you life (-100). Each dungeons increase your score (+100 for the conventional and + 1000 for the last one).

There are 9 villages where you can gain back some life (120) but you need to get a pass to enter the village (you start with 1 available and each visit of a dungeon). Two villages cannot be visited consecutively, you need to visit at least one other village in between (not a dungeon).

The target is to have the best score at the end.

So I started to search for each combination of point of interest the lowest cost path using a A* algorithm, with 2 different situations : ocean is an obstacle and ocean is not an obstacle (i.e; I have a boat).

Now I need to find the best sequence in term of dungeons / village / travel order to maximize the score. The problem is that some targets are "dynamic", meaning if life is below 100 for instance, I cannot visit a dungeon, or if the number of "pass" is zero, I cannot recover in a village. So it is a kind of dynamic diagram, with accessible neighbors being a function of history (cannot visit twice the same village in a row) and of the current status (life level).

I really don't know how to manage this and even where to start.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Sly

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The question is way too broad for SO.  This platform is more suitable for focuses specific programming issues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.